# How to change the color in python but retain its shade

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, rgb, hsv

I'd like to give an option to the user to change color of a particular pixel. If the particular pixel is **light** blue, and the user selects it to be green. How should I enforce the change to represent **light** green? In the vica versa case if the color of the pixel is **dark** blue, I'd like to enforce it to now represent **dark** green. Can this be done in HSV scale?

I have RGB values of each pixel

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to convert the image to HSV, change the value, and then convert it back to RGB.

Comment: What HSV value do i change? If only hue is changed to green, and saturation and value is kept constant does it ensure that the shade remains the same?